# Return name in ActiveRecord relation along with foreign key id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Sub-Component model which can belong to other sub-components. My Model looks like this:

```
class SubComponent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "SubComponent", foreign_key: "parent_sub_component_id", optional: true
  has_many :child_sub_components, class_name: "SubComponent", foreign_key: "parent_sub_component_id"

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

This model is fairly simple, it has a `name` field and a `parent_sub_component_id` which as the name suggests is an `id` of another `SubComponent`.

I'd like to generate a query that returns all of the `SubComponents` (with their `id`, `name`, and `parent_sub_component_id`) but also includes the actual name of it's parent_sub_component.

This seems like it should be pretty simple but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it. I'd like for this query to be done in the database rather than doing an each loop in Ruby or something like that.

EDIT:

I'd like for the output to look something like this:

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SubComponent id: 1, name: "Parent Sub", parent_sub_component_id: nil, parent_sub_component_name: nil created_at: "2017-07-07 00:29:37", updated_at: "2017-07-07 00:29:37">, #<SubComponent id: 2, name: "Child Sub", parent_sub_component_id: 1, parent_sub_component_name: "Parent Sub" created_at: "2017-07-07 00:29:37", updated_at: "2017-07-07 00:29:37">]>`

Comment: Do you mean every subcomponent of a specific parent component, as well as all the sub-subcomponents of those, regardless of how deep they are in the hierarchy? If not, can you give us an example output that you would like to achieve?

Comment: A SubComponent will only have one parent, so I'd like to get that parent's name along with it's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently using an `each` loop if you use `includes`:

```rb
SubComponent.all.includes(:parent).each do |comp|
  comp.parent.name  # this gives you the name of the parent
end
```

What `includes` does is it *pre-fetches* the specified association. That is, ActiveRecord will query all subcomponents, and then in a *single query* also pull down all the parents of those subcomponents. When you subsequently access `comp.parent` in the loop, the associated parent will already be loaded, so this will not result in a so-called *N+1 query*.

The queries that AR will generate for you automatically will look something like this:

```sql
SELECT `subcomponents`.* FROM `subcomponents`
SELECT `subcomponents`.* FROM `subcomponents` WHERE `subcomponents`.`id` IN (1, 3, 9, 14)
```

If you need to use the name of the parent in a `where` condition, `includes` will not work and you will have to use `joins` instead to actually generate an SQL `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but should get you started in the right direction, you can do this in Arel by doing something like

```
def self.execute_query
  parent_table = Arel::Table.new(:sub_component).alias
  child_table = Arel::Table.new(:sub_component)

child_table.join(parent_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(child_table[:parent_sub_component_id].eq(parent_table[:id]).project(child_table[:id], child_table[:name], parent_table[:id], parent_table[:name])
end
```

This results in a query like

```
SELECT "sub_component"."id", "sub_component"."name", "sub_component_2"."id", "sub_component_2"."name" FROM "sub_component" LEFT OUTER JOIN "sub_component" "sub_component_2" ON "sub_component"."parent_sub_component_id" = "sub_component_2"."id"
```

this is just off the top of my head by looking at [Rails/Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) and probably needs a some work, but the query looks about what I would expect and this should get you going.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to do this without a gem. This seems like something ActiveRecord should be able to do.

Comment: Arel is packaged with Rails by default. It is what ActiveRecord uses behind the scenes.